# Setting object property without creating additional nesting level

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var o = { dates: { dateFrom: "01DEC2012", dateTo: "02DEC2012" }, selection: "A" };
```

and a function:

```
var getSelection = function () {
   return { selection: "A,B" };
};
```

calling:

```
o.selection = getSelection();
```

gets me:

```
{ dates: { dateFrom: "01DEC2012", dateTo: "02DEC2012" }, selection: { selection: "A,B"} };
```

while I need:

```
{ dates: { dateFrom: "01DEC2012", dateTo: "02DEC2012" }, selection: "A,B" };
```

I know that I can fetch `getSelection()` result into a variable and then update `o` manually, but my object is a whole lot more complex, I need to to set the whole thing in one go. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially merging `getSelection()` into `o`, so you could do something like this:

```
var result = getSelection();

for (var key in result) {
    o[key] = result[key];
}
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use [`jQuery.extend()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend):

```
var result = jQuery.extend(getSelection(), result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your getSelection method:

```
var getSelection = function () {
   return "A,B";
};
```

Edit:
How about this:

```
o.selection = getSelection().selection;
```

Comment: sorry but the return of my function is a complex JSON.

Comment: will work, but the implementation will rely on the structure of getSelection() return, which I want to avoid.

Comment: If you're worried about undefined/null case scenarios, perhaps you can make the RHS of the assignment as a ternary operator? (To either retain the old value or take a valid value from the method call)